# Cannot read/write files from ubuntu hard drive plugged into another computer

Tags: drivers, permissions, hard-drive

Recently I tried to install the fglrx (AMD) graphics driver on my computer running Ubuntu 14.10. Long story short, it didn't work, and I messed up my computer pretty badly. Then I fixed it, and tried to install the driver again, because I'm stubborn! Anyway, no idea how to fix it this time, and I figured it would be easier to just reinstall Ubuntu.

The problem: My main hard drive is an SSD that has all my OS files, as well as my personal files on it. However, when I either use a hard drive caddy, or a Ubuntu USB stick plugged into my computer to try and backup my files, I can't read or write them because I don't have the right file permissions. I've tried using chmod and chown to change the permissions, but it seems like when the hard drive is plugged into another computer, (In this case, the same computer, but running off a live usb) it still won't let me access the files.

Any ideas? Also, has anyone else had trouble with the fglrx driver? In the past it's broken all of my games, and this time I can't get past the login screen into the GUI. I'll probably try an open-source driver next...

Answer (score 1):

Start from live iso (usb) and open the file manager as root by running `sudo nautilus` in a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). Then you will be able to edit all the files, or at least give yourself permissions to edit all the files.

Also, while in nautilus, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to see hidden files.